# How do I convert regular address text to Google Places autocomplete object

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have regular address string this "NYS97 Luxton Lake Road, Narrowsburg, New York, USA". How can I create google.maps.places.Autocomplete object with this address without specifying input element? I need this in cases when user refreshes the page with filling form and sees input already filled but have to reselect address to triger place_changed and get place from autocomplete object.
Here is my code:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  document.getElementById('id_address'),
  {types: ['address']});

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  console.log(place)
  var address_data = {
    'name': place.name,
    'formatted_address': place.formatted_address,
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      address_data[addressType] = place.address_components[i}[componentForm[addressType]];
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('id_address_data').value = JSON.stringify(address_data);
});
```

Comment: I believe autocomplete comes with the browser so check that first

Comment: @rodude123 You are right. But I need to use this browser autocoplete text to create 
 google autocomplete object.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some bits of code where I am setting an iFrame URL to a Google Maps address:

loc is a location object that contains the address.  I'm not including that code.

```
let mapURL1 = "//www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=";
let mapURL2 = "&key=yourmapskey";
let mapURLaddress = loc.Street + " " + loc.City + " " + loc.State + " " + loc.Zip;

mapURLaddress = mapURLaddress.Replace(' ', '+');

document.querySelector("#mapiFrame").src= mapURL1 + mapURLaddress + mapURL2;
```

Hopefully that helps.  You can store the address in a cookie and check the cookie on page load to see if you should restore the address on the map.